# Prestashop 1.7 Apaczka map module with quick purchases PRO module

Tags: javascript, module, prestashop

is someone tryied to install Quick Purchases Pro module?

I have a problem, when i am loading Apaczka map module, that script from this module wont work properly. It means window.onLoad wont load.

I have modified a apaczka script adding console.logs, and I will show differences at 2 different stores. One with QPPro module, second without.

[image]
[image]

Maybe someone know's why this won't work, because help centre from quick purchase PRO won't help without payment, while module is bought XDDD

I am using prestashop 1.7.7 and php 7.3.33

https://www.apaczka.pl/integracje/mapa-punktow-prestashop/

https://prestadev.pl/pl/moduly-prestashop/szybkie-zakupy-pro-dla-prestashop-17x.html

Update Question.

I found a problem. For some reason this module doesn't allow to run window.onLoad from Apaczka Map, I tryied to edit on load to function, this time button and map appears, but i am not sure is all works fine.

I am testing it. If you change to function you would have an error with button "ConfirmCarrierOption". I added condition, that if this button is not exist, dont run. This button is deleted by second module Quick Sell Pro.

1. A question is still active. Do you have an idea, how to repair onLoad that not work, and do you know how to check after order post point?
2. Probably i have to add this button to save point. Or I have to copy  point name to order description added by customer, but how to do it properly, cause it may be buggy if customer delete it.